# SelectList how to set selected item only when valid value for System.Web.Mvc.SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlist

When you create a SelectList you can optionally pass in the SelectedValue property for which the documentation says

```
// selectedValue:
// The selected value. Used to match the Selected property of the corresponding
// System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem.
```

However, if you pass it a value object which is not contained in the list of items, it still sets the selected value.  Try this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

class SomeItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

class CreateSelectList
{
    public static SelectList CreateSelectList() 
    {
        List<SomeItem> items = new List<SomeItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new SomeItem() { id = i, text = i.ToString() });
        }

        // 5 is not in the list of items yet the property SelectedValue does = 5
        return new SelectList(items, "id", "text", 5); 
     }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Since I want to lazily set my selected value only if it exists, I just want to pass in a value and have it ignored when it does not exist in the list, but how? (is this a bug or a design feature),  or
2. If you create a SelectList **without** the SelectedValue, after you have constructed it, how can you set the SelectedValue (again when it exists in the list) ?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is near to your real scenario, you could use something like this

```
// check if there is any element with id = 5 
if (items.Any(i => i.id == 5)) 
{
    // there is an element with id = 5 so I set the selected value
    return new SelectList(items, "id", "text", 5); 
}
else
{
    // there is no element with id = 5 so I don't set the selected value
    return new SelectList(items, "id", "text");
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but my code demonstrates the problem, my problem is that the real code uses generics and I neither know what the items are or the object type for the selected value, for example I don't actually know its called 'id' this is the method CreateSelectList<T>(List<T> items, ITitle emptyItem, object selectedValue)

Comment: @AndyM: why don't you select the element outside this generic function then? There could be approaches to do it inside the generic method, but I'd say you would overcomplicate it.